# Filter controls by type and property value using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there efficient way to filter Panel's child controls by their type e.g. `Label` property e.g. `Tag` value?

E.g. I have a panel1:

```
label1.Tag=1;
label2.Tag=1;
label3.Tag=2;
label4.Tag=3;
textBox1.Tag=1;
panel1.Add(controls above);
```

I would like to get all labels in the collection, or all the controls with `Tag=1`, or use `and` between the statements.

Comment: the most natural way is to loop through the Controls of your Panel and perform some if statement...

Comment: Have you tried anything? It would seem to me that something along the lines of `panel1.Controls.Where(c => c.Tag == 1)` should work quite simply.

Comment: I have a `foreach` loop with several `if` statements inside. I'm just looking for most efficient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter all controls of a specific type using the `OfType` extension method:

```
var labelControls = panel.Controls.OfType<Label>();
```

Then if you want to add additional filtering (e.g. based on the tag):

```
var filteredLabelControls = labelControls.Where(l => l.Tag == (object)1);
```

Comment: It seems, I was looking for something like this! Interesting solution!

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
foreach (var control in panel.Controls
                             .Cast<Control>()
                             .Where(c => object.Equals(c.Tag, 1))
{
    ...
}
```